# Broadcast or event doesnt do anything

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I wanted to add some pusher stuff on my app with laravel broadcasting however using broadcast() or event() helpers doesn't do anything and I have no errors.

Added my pusher info to env, changed broadcasting driver from log to pusher and neither worked. Created test event with channel name 'my-channel' and event name 'my-event'. Some dummy data in event and tried to call broadcast/event helpers with that event.

Also started PHP `artisan queue:work --tries=3`

And added composer require pusher/pusher-php-server

Nothing works, not even calling `event(new TestEvent())` from tinker.

Only thing that works is using Pusher class directly:

```
$P = NEW Pusher\Pusher('KEY','SECRET','ID', ['cluster' => 'eu']); 
$P->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', ['message' => 'test']);
```

Comment: Have you uncommented the following line in config/App.php?`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider`

Comment: yes i did :D....

Comment: For everyone, I am not sure what happened but from nowhere it solved itself :D

Answer (score -1):

do you implement your event on ShouldBroadcast ?

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
 ....
}
```